# python 2.7 unique calculation issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, I have a list, and each element in the list is a (sub-list) -- a list of tuples. I want to remove the duplicate sub-list, I post input and expected output. I tried to use `set`, but there is error said `list` is not hashable. Anyone have good elegant code solutions? Thanks.

```
a=[[(1,2),(1,3)],
   [(1,3),(1,2)],
   [(1,2),(1,3)]]

# expect output
'''
a=[[(1,2),(1,3)],
   [(1,3),(1,2)]]
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a set, something like below

```
a=[[(1,2),(1,3)],
   [(1,3),(1,2)],
   [(1,2),(1,3)]]
unique_list = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in a)]
print unique_list
```

Output:

> [[(1, 3), (1, 2)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]]

See working repl here - https://repl.it/EinE/1

Comment: Thanks pradeep1991singh, it seems tuple works for set, but list not works for set. Just curious to know why there is a diff? They are both a list of something.

Comment: BTW, mark your reply as answer, appreciate for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this! This is the simplest method.

```
a = [[(1,2),(1,3)],
     [(1,3),(1,2)],
     [(1,2),(1,3)]]

print [list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, a))]
```

> [[(1, 3), (1, 2)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]] //output

The above one is without any library support and also the ordering of the original list can't be ensured.

If you want to preserve the order of the list, then go for `collections` library.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = [[(1,2),(1,3)],
     [(1,3),(1,2)],
     [(1,2),(1,3)]]

print map(list, OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(tuple, a)))
```

> [[(1, 2), (1, 3)], [(1, 3), (1, 2)]] //output

Comment: Getting `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable` when running this.

Comment: @Vinay It's working for me here! Can't see why are you getting that error!

Comment: Hmm very strange yeah not sure I am either actually. tuple should be valid.

Comment: Derp I'm an idiot - assigned tuple in a loop while testing some stuff :-P

Comment: @Vinay What's your output for simply ```map(tuple, a)``` ? Does that gives you a list of tuples?

Comment: @Vinay Haha! No offense bro! It happens! :) Hope it works good now!

Comment: Thanks bharadhwaj, it seems tuple works for set, but list not works for set. Just curious to know why there is a diff? They are both a list of something.